# When an Object is sent back in fabric js, how to drag only with its control

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs

I have an fabric js element image and a textbox in my canvas. I sent the textbox to the back, placing it behind the image. However, the textbox controls are now visible, but when I try to drag the textbox, the front object (image) gets selected instead. This is because the image is positioned in front of the textbox controls. I want to be able to access and interact with the textbox controls even though they are positioned above the image. How can I achieve this?

[Added the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYa6V.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.